# "От около" -- возможно ли?

Tags: предлоги

От около 100 долларов до 200 долларов.

Можно ли так писать: от около, если необходимо указать именно то, что не точно 100 долларов, а меньше?

в словаре: около - это 3. Почти, приблизительно, немного меньше какой-л. меры

от чуть меньше 100 долларов - правильно ли будет?

Answer (score 2):

От около 100 долларов до 200 долларов - неверное сочетание.

**Из словаря:** ОКОЛО, I. нареч. Возле, рядом.  II. предлог. кого-чего. 1. Возле, вблизи  2. Вокруг. 3. **Почти, приблизительно**.

Таким образом, **около - это предлог**, а два разных предлога не могут находиться рядом.

Comment: *Таким образом, около - это предлог, а два разных предлога не могут находиться рядом* - бывает и не такое. Если предлоги не первообразные.  Но я боюсь, что - в значении "примерно"  - "около" надо признать наречием. См. здесь. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE&all=x

Comment: Снмаю, разобрался. См. мой ответ.

Answer (score 1):

"От чуть меньше" тоже не говорят. Пишите "от почти".

Comment: от около - возможно ли?

Answer (score 1):

А! Я знаю как проверить, что такое невозможно. 
Возьмите другой первый предлог, управляющий не родительным падежом, а любым другим. Например - К (чему).

*(Подошли) к [около двухсот долларов]*. - ну никак такое невозможно сказать. Потому что надо *"к примерно двумстам долларам"*. К "около двумстам" - не получается. Значит, "около" тут действительно предлог - и именно он требует родительного падежа.

Попытка соединить несоединимое в исходном варианте спряталась за то, что оба предлога требовали родительного, поэтому не сразу было разоблачена.

*Еще один похожий случай соединения несоединимого - "от/до в три раза больше (лучше, быстрее)". Очень любят рекламщики такое: "волосы стали до пяти раз пушистее". Но там хоть альтернативы нет нормативной. А у нас есть слово "примерно"*.

Answer (score 1):

> Можно ли так писать: ***от около,*** если необходимо указать именно
>   то, что не точно…

Ну а почему же нельзя?

По поводу ***от около…*** В южно-славянских языках известны [*"очень разнообразные сочетания первичных предлогов с предлогом **около**"*](https://books.google.ru/books?id=42sMAAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%22%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&dq=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%22%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwikrO_PxZfMAhXDbZoKHecYA3oQ6AEIGzAA).

Ну а что в русском? Да тоже так говорят, причём не самые неграмотные люди. К примеру, доктор филологических наук  ***[В. В. Потапов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2,_%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87)***:

> КРИТСКОЕ ЛИНЕЙНОЕ ПИСЬМО  А (Linear A) — недешифрованное письмо о.
>   Крит, которое использовалось **от около** 1700 до 1600 гг. до н. э.
>
> [***В. В. Потапов. Краткий лингвистический справочник: языки и
>   письменность.***](https://books.google.ru/books?id=P3YbAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%22&dq=%22%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwizspWjv5bMAhXD3SwKHZPqBmw4ggEQ6AEIKTAE)